Find $q$ such that $5q^{\prime\prime}+3q^{\prime}=p$ using Linear Algebra
I wish to verify the veracity of the following proof in particular I want check if argument establishing $\operatorname{null}T=\operatorname{span}(1,z)$ and subsequently $\dim\operatorname{null}T=2$ is correct ? Any suggestions leading to a more efficient proof are welcome as well.

Suppose $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$. Prove that there exists a
polynomial $q\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$ such that
$5q^{\prime\prime}+3q^{\prime}=p$.


Proof. Let $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$ and let $\deg p=m$. Now define the map $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}_{m+2}(\mathbf{R}),
> \mathcal{P}_m({\mathbf{R}}))$ such that
$Tq=5q^{\prime\prime}+3q^\prime$. Observe now that $Tr=0$ if and only
if $\deg r\le1$, consequently
$\operatorname{null}T=\operatorname{span}(1,z)$. and the list $1,z$
serves as a basis for $\operatorname{null}T$ thus
$\dim\operatorname{null}T=2$.
3.21 then implies that $\dim\operatorname{range}T=\dim\mathcal{P}_{m+2}(\mathbf{R})-\dim\operatorname{null}T=(m+3)-2=m+1$,
thus $\dim\operatorname{range}{T}=\dim\mathcal{P}_m({\mathbf{R}})$,
requiring the map $T$ to be surjective, thus $p=Tq$ for some
$q\in\mathcal{P}_{m+2}(\mathbf{R})$

References and Notation

Result 3.21 above refers to the Rank-Nullity Theorem
$\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$ is the set of all real valued polynomials.
$\mathcal{P}_m(\mathbf{R})$ is the set of all real-valued polynomials with degree at most $m$
$\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ refers to set of all linear maps from the vector spaces $V$ to $W$.
The exercise above is problem 29 from section 3B from Linear Algebra Done Right
The list of functions $1,z,z^2,\dots,z^m$ represent the standard basis of  $\mathcal{P}_m(\
\mathbf{R})$.


What is $z{}{}$?

I think it would be a better idea to show that you can obtain every element of the standard basis as a solutions of $Tq(x)=x^n$ for every $n$. The last part of your proof seems fishy to me.

If $\deg q=m+2$, $\deg T(q)=m+1>m$. And $z\notin\operatorname{null}T=\operatorname{span}(1)$.

@JoséCarlosSantos apologies for that abuse of notation, post has been updated to account for this.

Then $5z''+3z'=3\ne0$, and therefore $z\notin\operatorname{null}T$.

Indeed, as told before. Now that your two mistakes have been detected, your final question (about "more efficient proofs") is a duplicate of  Prove that the polynomial $q$ exists..

@AnneBauval Thank you for all your responses, I think I missed that link, closing this post.
